# Swapping div content from another JSP page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, servlets

I basically have 4 pages:

affiliates-manage.jsp (contains code below):

```
<%@ include file="/includes/core.jsp" %>
<div name="tableframe" id="tableframe">
  <c:import url = "{URL}/servlets/Vendors.Affiliates">
    <c:param name = "SESSIONID" value = "${sessionid}" />
    <c:param name = "ACTION" value = "-1"/>
    <c:param name = "ROWTEMPLATEURL" value = "{URL}/affiliates-manage-tablerow.html"/>
    <c:param name = "NEXT_PAGE" value = "{URL}/affiliates-manage-start.jsp"/>
    <c:param name = "ERROR_PAGE" value = "{URL}/error_frame.jsp"/>
  </c:import>
</div>
```

affiliates-manage-start.jsp (contains code below):

```
function submitForm (action, target, nextpage, affiliateid) {
  var form = document.affiliates;
  form.ACTION.value = action;
  form.target = target;
  form.NEXT_PAGE.value = nextpage;
  form.ERROR_PAGE.value = (target == "_parent") ? "{URL}/error.jsp" : "{URL}/error_frame.jsp";
  form.AFFILIATEID.value = affiliateid;
  form.submit ();
}

function editAffiliate (affiliateid) {
  submitForm (1, "tableframe", "{URL}/affiliates-manage-edit.jsp", affiliateid);
}
```

affiliates-manage-tablerow.html (contains code below):

```
<a href="javascript:editAffiliate (##AFFILIATEID##)">##AFFILIATEID##</a>
```

affiliates-manage-edit.jsp (displays a table to edit the affiliates info):

```
<%@ include file="/includes/core.jsp" %>
<div class="transfer-section">
  <form name="affiliates" action="{URL}}/servlets/Vendors.Affiliates" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ACTION" value="11" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AFFILIATEID" value="${param.AFFILIATEID}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="NEXT_PAGE" value="{URL}/affiliates-manage-edited.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ERROR_PAGE" value="{URL}/error_frame.jsp" />
    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 1rem; width: 70%; border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;">
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-category text-center">
          <th class="sort-column">Product&nbsp;Name</th>
          <th class="sort-column">Default&nbsp;Percentage</th>
          <th class="sort-column">Custom&nbsp;Percentage</th>
        </tr>
        ${param.TABLEDATA}
      </thead>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="submitForm (affiliates);" class="save-btn" style="margin-right: .3rem;" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.reload();" class="save-btn" />
  </form>
</div> <!-- end .transfer-section -->
```

My goal is to swap the `tableframe` content to the `affiliates-manage-edit.jsp` content for that selected affiliate (affiliateid). I've tried adding `$('#tableframe').load('affiliates-manage-edit.jsp');` and `$('#tableframe').load('affiliates-manage-edit.jsp, affiliateid');` under the `submitForm()` inside of `editAffiliate()` and it opens everything properly in a new window (which I don't want), but in the original window it doesn't display the `${param.TABLEDATA}` information (leaves it blank). I have tried several different things and the `.load()` has gotten me closest so far.

Comment: What should `${param.TABLEDATA}` display ? Also does `${param.AFFILIATEID}` displaying required value?

Comment: Those pull in data from the database. The `AFFILIATEID` doesn't actually display on the `edit` page anywhere by default, it's just used to pull their information (products, percentage, etc.).